# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

please check my proof

$$\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}< \epsilon $$

$$\frac{-1^{2n}}{n}< \epsilon ^{2} $$

$$\frac{1}{n^{2}}< \epsilon ^{2} $$

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon ^2}< n^{2} $$

Then choose $N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon ^2}$

therefore $n>N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon ^{2}}$

Limit equal 0

Comment: There is one big flaw in your proof: It contains too many symbols and not enough words. Mathematical proofs are usually formed in complete coherent sentences. Your proof, while it looks valid, is simply a series of equations (well, inequalities) and very hard to follow. Next time, try telling a story to the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to show that the limit of the sequence $a_n$ as $\to\infty$ is $0$, we have to show that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\ge1$ such that
$$
|a_n-0|=|a_n|<\varepsilon
$$
for $n>N$.

We have to show that for each $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\biggl|\frac{(-1)^{n}}n\biggr|<\varepsilon
$$
for $n>N$. So you do not have to square it. We have that
$$
\biggl|\frac{(-1)^{n}}n\biggr|=\frac1n<\varepsilon
$$
and we can choose any $N>1/\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion  ^ ^.I square because I wanted to make it positve

Comment: @Fourier You need to take the absolute value and then $(-1)^n$ disappears, you only have to deal with $1/n$.

Comment: ok ,thank you again  ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

The idea is alright but you don't have to square, since $a_n \to 0$ if $|a_n|$ can be made arbitrarily small:
$$\left| a_n \right| = \left| \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right|= \left| \frac{1}{n} \right| = \frac{1}{n} $$